# How to solve AttributeError caused by overriden method

Tags: python, methods, overriding, super, attributeerror

I try to find the reason I get an Attribute error when I override a method in a subclass that access a attribute introduced in that subclass.

In the code below  you can see that `B` works fine, but the error only occurs when I reference the new attribute in the overridden method in `C`.

I thought that I maybe had to call the populate method again, but that seems not to be the case.

```
# some class that uses a method to populate one of it's attributes
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.populate()

    # The original populating method
    def populate(self):
        self.x = 5

my_obj = A()
print(my_obj.x)

# I can make a subclass that works fine AND has a new attribute
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.y = 9

    def populate(self):
        self.x = 5

my_obj = B()
print(my_obj.x)
print(my_obj.y)


class C(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.z = 7
        self.populate()

    # This method overides the original one and causes an attribute error
    # because self.z is unknown
    def populate(self):
        self.x = self.z

my_obj = C()
print(my_obj.x)
```

Comment: I removed some of the irrelevant noise in your code (parameters, etc). Let me know if I messed something up, or just roll back the edit.

Comment: No, you made the question more general and clear. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you need the attribute `x` when initializing your object `C`. In `A.__init__` the call to `self.populate()` is already the overriding method, i.e. `C.populate` and it requires `self.x`.

You can set `self.z` before calling the parent's `__init__` method:

```
class C(A):
    def __init__(self):
        self.z = 7
        super().__init__()

    def populate(self):
        self.x = self.z
```

Comment: Ah... yeah, that makes sense. Thank you!